# Having trouble understanding the tinyxml tutorial and how to use it

Tags: c++, object, tinyxml

I've had a thorough look at the tinyxml (C++) tutorial but still can't really understand how I apply the examples to what I'm trying to do. What I'm trying to do in short is use an xml to generate a series of room objects in a game. Is someone able to give me a short example with the following xml and Room object, please? Xml is:

```
<room>
    <name>Prison room</name>
    <connections>
    <connection>Guard room</connection>
    </connections>
  <items>
    <item>
      <name>Short sword</name>
      <attack>2</attack>
       <armor>0</armor>
    </item>
  </items>
  <monsters></monsters>
</room>
```

Room object has the following fields:

```
std::vector<Item> itemsInRoom;
std::vector<Room> connectingRooms;
std::vector<Monster> monstersInroom;
std::string roomName;
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Removed the edit as that particular problem was solved.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? What is the result you are getting instead of the one you were expecting? First, try working out something yourself and then when you are running into a problem, we can help. Just asking for an example based on your use case isn't really how this website works.

Comment: I can't get started on it because I don't understand how to start or what to do, that's what the question is about =/

Comment: Then I'm afraid we can't help you because you can't get started. I can't load the TinyXML page at the moment, but a good way to start by copying from the tutorial and start modifying it to your use case.

Comment: I've already said I've tried to look at the tutorial and understand it, but I literally cannot get off the ground with it. I'm not sure what the problem with asking someone to write a very simple example of how to do what I posted above is?

Comment: Hey, if anyone is using TinyXML (and I am), you may have noticed everything in the tutorial is outdated. TiXMLDocument doesn't exist. For some reason, NextSibling() and NextSiblingElement() always fail even when you print to the correct spot. You have to search SO to find XMLDocument to be the right item to use, and while it compiles fine on android and iOS, and you can get the Value()s, it's much more difficult than JSON and RapidXML just to get started, so this guy is just one unlucky newbie who started with "the harder one" Like everyone says, get familiar with data structs and design 1st!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do would be to learn more about XML and about representing/structuring/abstracting data. For example, it is usually unwise to encode e.g. the item "short sword" inside the room as you do. Rather you would want to provide a definition of that item (or a template of it) somewhere else and only have a reference to that, possibly with some extra parameters inside the room node. You will probably also want to learn to use attributes (all data is *not* the same, some data *should* be attributes).

Once you have groked that, the actual TinyXML stuff is easy. TinyXML is about as simple as it can get:

1. Agree on some semantics. Write them down, remember them, follow them when you create the XML files.
2. Create a `TiXmlDocument`, give it the name of your data file
3. Call `LoadFile` on your document object
4. Call `FirstChildElement`, giving you the root node (note that if you have more than one room in the XML you need to have a separate root node!)
5. Iterate over the cildren using `FirstChildElement` and `NextSiblingElement`.
6. Now you have to remember the structure of your XML file (or the semantics of its elements). TinyXML *cannot magically figure that out for you*.
7. Use `FirstChildElement` and `NextSiblingElement` in the same manner as for the room nodes for "anything inside" each room (whatever you decided that may be) to figure out what each room looks like and what's in them. *You must know what this data means, TinyXML cannot know this kind of thing, it merely provides you with structured data.*
8. Resolve references and set up the corresponding data structures (e.g. when you have something like `<door to="guard_room" x="5" y="3" status="locked" />` create the necessary links so your game reacts appropriately.

(and don't forget to check for errors)

The tutorials at the TinyXML site are also very easy to understand (last I looked some 2-3 years ago, you could basically copy-paste them). If these really pose a considerable problem, I'd reconsider the idea of writing a RPG for the time being. I'm not saying forever, but at least until you have enough experience to follow these.

Comment: Can you explain why it is unwise as you say to encode the short sword item inside the room?

Comment: A game has many swords. There may be big swords and small ones, blunt and sharp, but every sword is more or less the same. It has a handle and a blade, and you swing it at someone to cut him up. This "common logic" is best encoded _once_ somewhere, and modified by parameters as appropriate, rather than repeating redundant information again and again. It's easier, it uses less memory, less computing power, and most importantly there is less room for making silly errors.

Comment: Ok, so would I use a separate xml file for that then? Also, could you take a look at my edit? :) I gave your advice a go..

Comment: You can use one or many XML files, as you desire. I would put things that belong together (e.g. all item templates, or all rooms) in one file. Your code snippet above won't work like that, first because the XML file has no root node (thus, the room _is the root node_). Well-formed XML has one single root node. But this means you can only have one room per file if you do it this way... that is not very efficient (though, possible). Next, you must get child and sibling nodes _as appropriate_. The root's first _child_ is the first room (or whatever), this one's _sibling_ is the next.

Comment: You must really _understand_ the structure (picture it in your mind, like a tree). TinyXML will do what you ask it to do, not more  and not less. If you ask it to return something that doesn't make sense or doesn't exist, it will just return `null` (and your program will crash when you try to dereference that without checking for errors). So in one word, the code you write must match the structure in your XML file, and that one should have a sane layout. Wrapping the room node into another rooms node (for example) would provide a proper root node and allow for many rooms in one file.

Comment: Aha! Thanks! :) I just changed all the calls to FirstChildElement, and now roomName is actually that :) So how would I link to the other xml docs inside this xml doc if I had an xml doc with items/monsters in?

Comment: I dont really understand why I need to have a <rooms> node inside my <roomConfig> node, it seems a bit pointless, as there'd be nothing else inside <roomConfig> besides <rooms>...

Comment: Well, if you actually have a `<roomConfig>` node as root node, then all is good, you don't need it then. It's just that the snippet you posted above does __not__ contain a `<roomConfig>` root node. From what you posted, the `room` node would be your root, which would mean you can only have one room per file for the document to be well-formed.

Comment: Ah yea sorry, assuming other people magically know what my actual xml file is :P nah, I do have a <roomConfig> node as root :)

Comment: I'm gonna mark this answer as accepted as I've got the hang of the basics now - if I have any other issues they'd be better off in another question, and this back-and-forth here has gotten rather long :) thanks for your help!